# Can you determine if an event was created from Salesforce or from Apex in Apex?

Tags: apex

Is there any possible way to determine if an event was created from the Salesforce UI, or through Apex in Apex code? I have a situation where all day events created from Salesforce have the correct time length, but all day events created within Apex had to be set 24 hours ahead to actually cover that last day (using custom UI).

So an event created from the custom UI that went from 06-02 to 06-04 actually had to be set to 06-05 as the last day at midnight to cover the entire day of the 4th.

I now have need to determine which events were created with the custom UI to remove 24 hours from them, but not do that to the events that were created from Salesforce as they have the correct end date.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is it a schedule/batch which was creating events?

Comment: No, it was just an apex remote method. They clicked save in our UI, then the remote method assembled the event in the controller and inserted it.

Comment: I don't think there is any direct way, until unless you did something different during creating event. Like subject text or anything else which quite uniquely represent event created from Custom UI.

Comment: Dang, I may not be able to do any conversions for people then... I may just have to warn them that their all day events may be one day longer than they desire, which isn't great, but I haven't found anything else to be done with this.

Comment: This may be an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If possible, you should fix the custom UI so it matches the intended logic.

Comment: I did now. The issue is it did handle all day events differently. We are utilizing a library and has to have the events actually span the time they were supposed to cover, while Salesforce let's all day events end 12am on their last day. I now have a custom functionality built to be able to fully mimick Salesforce handling of all day events. The problem now is all day events previously created will be one day longer than the should.